# What does "Your bundle is locked to addressable " mean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundle, jekyll

I'm trying to `bundle exec jekyll serve`

but I get this error:

```
Your bundle is locked to addressable (2.5.0), but that version could not be found in any of the sources listed in your Gemfile. If you haven't changed sources, that means the author of addressable (2.5.0) has removed it. You'll need to update your bundle to a different version of addressable (2.5.0) that hasn't been removed in order to install.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

`bundle install` gives me

```
Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.13.6) is older than the version that created the lockfile (1.13.7). We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
```

This works, but it gives me the wrong version I think:

```
Successfully installed bundler-1.15.1
Parsing documentation for bundler-1.15.1
Done installing documentation for bundler after 4 seconds
1 gem installed
```

Where is the bundle locked to adressable and what does this mean? I checked my gemfile, it's nothing in there. Can I unlock it? I'm trying to run a boilerplate for jekyll and installed ruby using brew.

Comment: Try `bundle update` and then do `bundle exec jekyll serve`

Comment: It seems i'm running different versions of ruby... it says, `liquid-4.0.0 requires ruby version >= 2.1.0, which is incompatible with the
current version, ruby 2.0.0p648` but when I try brew update ruby, it says `Error: ruby 2.4.1_1 already installed`

Comment: `brew update ruby`? Are you not using RVM or RBenv?

Answer (score 0):

The "Your bundle is locked to addressable..." error just means that you have a version of addressable specified in your Gemfile.lock, but it's not installed on your machine (yet). Running `bundle install` fixes that.

As such, if you run the following, your app should run just fine:

```
$ bundle install
$ bundle exec jekyll serve
```

The "Bundler (1.13.6) is older..." warning is just an FYI from the good people at Bundler, encouraging you to upgrade. You can safely ignore it without it affecting your app (but it's good practice to stay up-to-date).